# Download LINK for product all images magento

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, product-images

I am new to Magento. I have a Magento 1.9 site where I am required to provide a Downloadable link for all images of a particular product that should automatically get downloaded on button click.

Is there any free extension for this purpose.  Please help me

Answer (score 4):

Actually their is no need of any third party extension for this task you can implement the same by your own.

**This is with assumption that you want the download button or link on product detail page.**

Place the following code on `app\design\frontend\<YOUR_PACKAGE>\<YOUR_THEME>\template\catalog\product\view.phtml`

```
<?php
                $file_arr=array();
                foreach ($_product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) :
                    array_push($file_arr, (string) Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $image->getFile()));
                endforeach;
                create_zip($file_arr);

                function create_zip($files = array())
                {
                    $zip = new ZipArchive;
                    $res = $zip->open('ProductImages.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
                    if ($res === TRUE) {
                        foreach ($files as $file) {
                            $download_file = file_get_contents($file);
                            $zip->addFromString(basename($file), $download_file);
                        }
                        $zip->close();
                    }
                }
                $url =  Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Url::XML_PATH_SECURE_URL);
                ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $url.'ProductImages.zip'?>">Download</a>
```

I have implement the code with download link by some modification you can achieve the same with button.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: can you give me magento2 code for same thanks